# Ways in which code can be optimize to run in timelimit

Tags: c

you are given an unsorted array we have to find minimum number of swaps required to sort an array in ascending order

code written by me works but it is not optimized code.this problem is from hackerRank( https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-swaps-2/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays ) it runs out timelimit when array size is like 100000

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int swap=0;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    int arr[num];
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]==i+1)
        {}
        else 
        {
            for(int j=i;j<num;j++)
            {
                if(i+1==arr[j])
                {
                    int temp=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=arr[j];
                    arr[j]=temp;
                    swap++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",swap);
    return 0;
}
```

it is the link for test case where it runs out of time
https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/70816/input10.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1569437814&Signature=zGqla8NqSOENSPJNt%2BkokJBX%2Fmk%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain
so provide ways to optimize code

Comment: I'd say you need to use a different algorithm, with a lower time complexity. Which algorithms have you tried?

Comment: Your're using an O(n^2) algorithm. There are much better algorithms for this; in fact, you can get it down to O(n).

Comment: That's the point of the challenge: not just to find the answer, but to find the right algorithm.

Comment: suggest me a bettter way by which i can find minimum swaps

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker i want to find minimum swaps within limits if i use bubble sort then swap no increases suggest me a better algorithm

Comment: As WV said, the point of the exercise is to learn how to choose the right algorithm. Google "minimum swaps algorithm" and learn.